# PHP/SQL Where, And, Order By -- works on one statement but getting an error on another similar query

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to add a section that shows if any year end awards are won by an individual. I have any Champions and Reserve Champions showing just fine. However, when I went to add the "year end awards" section I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'show = `yearend` ORDER BY year DESC' at line 1

I have played around with apostrphes, using a LIKE statement, removing the ORDER BY, and anything I could think of but I am at a loss. I can't seem to figure out what changed from the working statements that would cause an error.

**This works just fine**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id']; //Gets the ID from the URL
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM competition 
WHERE id = $id 
AND place = 'CH' 
ORDER BY year DESC") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['class'];
echo "<small>(";
echo $row['show'];
echo ")</small><br>";
}
?>
```

**This does not work**
The only change I made in the below is place = is now show =

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id']; //Gets the ID from the URL
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM competition 
WHERE id = $id 
AND show = 'yearend' 
ORDER BY year DESC") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['class'];
echo "<br>"; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHOW` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You have to take it into back ticks or better yet don't use reserved words as column names and just rename that column. It will save you time and hairs in a long run.

Change

```sql
AND show = 'yearend'
```

to

```sql
AND `show` = 'yearend'
    ^    ^
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that it is better rename the column in general so that you don't have to keep treating it with special gloves in each and every single query. +1 anyhow.

Comment: @Fluffeh I just did. Thanks. :)

Comment: Ah ha! I had no idea. Thank you so much. I was getting very frustrated with this.